# String to calendar with timezone in android

Tags: java, android, timezone

I Looking for a method that convert time string into Calendar look like this:

```
   public static Calendar stringToCalendar(String strDate, TimeZone timezone){
    String FORMAT_DATETIME = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT_DATETIME);
    sdf.setTimeZone(timezone);
    Date date = sdf.parse(strDate);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(timezone);
    cal.setTime(date);
    return cal;
   }
```

This code above does not work.
For example: when I pass time string '*2012-05-08T09:10:10*' with pattern **yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss** and Timezone is GMT+7, the result (from Calendar object) should be: *2012-05-08T16:10:10*
The problem is for some reasons, I don't want to use [Joda time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). So, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and set the [TimeZone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29) on it. Then invoke the `parse()` method.

EDIT:

---

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class temp2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String s = "2012-05-08T09:10:10";
        Calendar cal = stringToCalendar(s, TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0"));
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+7"));
        System.err.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
    }

    public static Calendar stringToCalendar(String strDate, TimeZone timezone) throws ParseException {
        String FORMAT_DATETIME = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT_DATETIME);
        sdf.setTimeZone(timezone);
        Date date = sdf.parse(strDate);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        return cal;
    }

}
```

outputs:

> 2012-05-08 16:10:10
> Where the difference is indeed 7 hours

Comment: @R4j The problem is that you are doing things in reverse. You are asking to convert a date and time from GMT+7 to your TimeZone

Comment: Thanks, I made a mistake. I want to convert date time from UTC to my TimeZone (GMT +7). Can you give me an example?

Comment: @R4j I updated my post. Simply switched the TimeZone's. Pass GMT+0 to the method and when you print it, use GMT+7.